# Creating a proc to check if an Integer is < 100

Tags: ruby

**I'm blanking big time on this one. This is all i've got. Help all mighty Overflow gods!**

```
ages = [23, 101, 7, 104, 11, 94, 100, 121, 101, 70, 44]
under_100 = Proc.new { |x| x < 100 }
```

Comment: Why you need `Proc` ?

Comment: So? What have you tried?

Comment: Basically i'm having a difficult time understanding why I don't need to specify an if statement to under_100. The proc is meant to check if each integer is under 100. I dunno, i'm sorta lost in this concept -_-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do as below

```
ages = [23, 101, 7, 104, 11, 94, 100, 121, 101, 70, 44]
under_100 = Proc.new { |x| x < 100 }
ages.select(&under_100) # => [23, 7, 11, 94, 70, 44]
ages.select { |x| x < 100 } # I would do this way or
ages.select(&100.method(:>)) # this way.
```

`100.method(:>)` created [`Method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Method.html) object(check this [`Object#method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-method)), same as the one you created as `Proc.new { |x| x < 100 }`. Now applying `&` to that *proc/method* object converting it to a *block* with `#select` method.

Comment: One also could use my [ampersand_x](https://github.com/goshakkk/ampersand_x) gem to do it like `ages.select(&X > 100)` which is more expressive :)

Comment: `100.method(:>)` does not create a `Proc` object but instance of `Method`: `100.method(:>).is_a? Proc # false`. Also beware of commutativity, as the resulting condition is inverted. Imagine an example with `Fixnum#-` or `Fixnum#/`.

Comment: @DavidUnric Thanks.. That was my mistyping.. Yes.. I am aware of commutativity... :) Thanks for bringing it into my notice.

Answer (score 0):

```
ages = [23, 101, 7, 104, 11, 94, 100, 121, 101, 70, 44]
under_100 = Proc.new { |x| x < 100 }

p under_100.call(201) #=> false
p under_100.call(23)  #=> true
```

Map runs the proc on each element and returns the result:

```
p ages.map(&under_100) #=> [true, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, false, true, true]
```

Select goes through all elements and only returns the ones that evaluates to true:

```
p ages.select(&under_100) #=> [23, 7, 11, 94, 70, 44]
```

It could also be written like this:

```
result = []
ages.each{|age| result.push(age) if under_100.call(age)}
p result #=> [23, 7, 11, 94, 70, 44]
```

So that is why you do not need to use any `if` when using the `select` method of the Array.

Answer (score 0):

without proc we can check it  as

```
ages = [23, 101, 7, 104, 11, 94, 100, 121, 101, 70, 44]

    ages.each do |x|  
      if x < 100;  
      puts "#{x} is less than 100";  
     end  
    end
```